# When to use a Singleton in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton, instance

There are many questions related to the use of the Singleton pattern in python, and although this question might repeat many of the aspects already discussed, I have not found the answer to the following specific question.

Let's assume I have a class `MyClass` which I want to instantiate only exactly once. In python I can do this as follows in the code `myclass.py`:

```
class MyClass(object): 
    def foo(self):
        ....


instance = MyClass()
```

Then in any other program I can refer to the instance simply with

```
import myclass
myclass.instance.foo()
```

Under what circumstances is this approach enough? Under what circumstances is the use of a Singleton pattern useful/mandatory?

Comment: consider the logging mechanism in a large application, for that you would prefer to have a single logger object to be accessed everywhere, rather than passing it everywhere you can just instantiate a new object, here you can use the singleton pattern

Comment: Consider the fact that python can do both OO and simple imperative things. Your (or any) use case might be served just fine by a module that has the function `foo`.

Comment: One of the best examples (imho) is a connection pool. For example, when connecting to your database you want to limit the total amount of connections and reuse the old connections if possible. This is the perfect location for a singleton/borg pattern approach.

Comment: Logging is a bad example: create a separate logger for each module and you can then control them independently. The connection pool sounds fine until you write unit tests for it, then you may want to create a new pool for each test. In general unit tests and singletons are not a good fit and I'd prefer testable code every time.

Answer (score 9):

The singleton pattern is more often a matter of convenience than of requirement. Python is a little bit different than other languages in that it is fairly easy to mock out singletons in testing (just clobber the global variable!) by comparison to other languages, but it is neverthess a good idea to ask yourself when creating a singleton: am I doing this for the sake of convenience or because it is stricly necessary that there is only one instance? Is it possible that there may be more than one in the future?

If you create a class that really will be only constructed once, it may make more sense to make the state a part of the module, and to make its methods into module-level functions. If there is a possibility that the assumption of exactly one instance may change in the future, then it is often much better to pass the singleton instance around rather than referencing the singleton through a global name.

For example, you can just as easily implement a "singleton" this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   instance = MyClass()
   doSomethingWith(instance)
```

In the above, "instance" is singleton by virtue of the fact that it is constructed only once, but the code that handles it is provided the instance rather than referencing `module.instance`, which makes it easier to reuse pieces of the code if, in some future situation, you need more than one `MyClass`.

Comment: That approach only works if the module is used in the main code. In my case, the class (for which only one instance must exist), is only used in other modules.

Comment: problem with module-level instances is that if someday you want to convert to lazily constructed object(instead of import time construction) - it will be quite problematic. Class attribute works much better for this purpose - you can convert it to `property`.

Comment: @Alex, even if it is not used by main directly, at some point you will have a top-level point at which the object can be instantiated and then passed down to subsequent calls.

Comment: @kerim You can then refactor the module to instantiate its state on first access.

Comment: @Deestan - how can you do it in Python?

Comment: @Deestan: Isn't that what you describe in your comment a singleton pattern then?

Comment: @Deestan: I'd like to know how a module could instantiate its state on first access if that access is through a module attribute which is not a function, such as `instance`. AFAIK, modules can't have properties.

Comment: @martineau - I assumed module state/functionality access was purely through functions, as that's the only implementation that makes sense to me.  Otherwise, it would not be a singleton substitute but just a wad of global state.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to use a module as a singleton as Michael Aaron Safyan suggests, you can make it work even if the module isn't imported by the main code by doing something like the following (in the main code or a module it does import direct or indirectly). What it does is make an`instance`class attribute initialized it to one, and then replaces the module object in`sys.modules`with the instance created:

```
class _MyClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo()'

_MyClass.instance = _MyClass()

import sys
_ref = sys.modules[__name__]  # Reference to current module so it's not deleted
sys.modules[__name__] = _MyClass.instance
```

I've found singletons a useful way to implement "registers" of things when it makes sense to have only one (registry) -- such as a group of classes for a class factory, a group of constants, or a bundle of configuration information. In many cases just a regular Python module will do fine because, **by default**, they're effectively already singletons due to fact that those already loaded get cached in the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.modules#sys.modules)dictionary.

Occasionally however, class instances are preferable because they can be passed construction parameters and have [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=properties#properties) -- something built-in module objects don't and can't be made to possess. Limitations like that can be worked-around using the trick shown above which effectively turns custom class instances into module objects.

The idea of using class instances as module objects is from [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli)'s [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) recipe named [*Constants in Python*](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, there are two sides to the singleton pattern.

- you want a single context for a given service because more than one does not make sense.
- you want to absolutely prevent people from creating two object of a given type because it might break your service

While the first case may have some applications (logging service), the second one is often the sign of a bad design.

You should design your API so that your users should not have to think about this problem. But if they dig through your undocumented layers to find your hidden constructor and want to use it for whatever reason, they should not have to deal with useless constructs created to prevent them to do what they need to do.